# SUDZC for objective c returning only the first object from a list of objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sudzc

Generated the code by using SUDZC tool it is working fine ,but it returning only the first object from a list of objects returned from Web service.

actually i NSLogged the response in didReceiveData and it returns three objects with different nodes. but at the handler side i shows only first element?

i have commented the code in connectionDidFinishLoading: in SoapRequest.m

```
 element = [element childAtIndex:0];
```

but no changes in the receiver side value.

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug many seems to run into with Sudzc and it's a problem with the deserializment where it creates a dictionary and if you don't have unique keys it will just keep replacing it.

It won't work just to comment out the part, but you're on the right track.

There's a couple of workarounds for it, you can check it out at the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/sudzc/issues/detail?id=19) on Sudzc.

I can't test the code myself at the moment, but check the different workarounds out and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: but i tried the solutions that discussed in issue tracker,, no hope..  :(

Comment: No difference at all or do you get another error? Some more information would help.